# IntelliJ Tomcat + PostgreSQL JDBC Connection Issue - java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

**[FIXED] *UPD: Successfuly fixed.* Importing the driver through maven and adding Class.forName() before creating Connection helped me ( although it was mentioned almost everywhere that the construct is considered deprecated since Java 8, apparently it has not lost its usefulness ). I hope my solution will help someone who finds himself in a similar situation.**

I am learning to work with PostgreSQL and the Tomcat server. I haven't encountered such issues when working with MySQL, and there were no driver problems when using Eclipse (I added the driver to the server's classpath, and everything worked perfectly).

Now, when I'm attempting to run the most basic program for database operations (retrieving a pre-prepared list of books from my database), the following error occurs:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at com.ex.dynamicweb.DBHandler.getBooks(DBHandler.java:22)
    at com.ex.dynamicweb.HelloServlet.doGet(HelloServlet.java:23)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

The issue is resolved solely by adding the JDBC driver to the tomcat/lib folder. However, are there any ways to automatically add this driver directly through the IDE? I tried changing Deployment, Artifacts (manually added the lib folder to WEB-INF in the exploded war), manually specified the path to the driver through libraries, imported JDBC Driver using maven, and added it to Modules - none of this helped solve my problem. Perhaps someone has encountered this?

JDBC Driver: 42.6.0
PostgreSQL: 16
Java: 11
Tomcat: 10.1.16 ( same problem 8.5.96 )
IntelliJ Ultimate 2023

I'm providing the code for my program as well as screenshots of the mentioned Artifacts/Modules/Libraries for reference:

idex.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Books</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><%= "Hello World!" %>
</h1>
<br/>
<a href="hello-servlet">Hello Servlet</a>
</body>
</html>
```

HelloServlet.java

```
package com.ex.dynamicweb;

import java.io.*;

import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.*;

@WebServlet(name = "helloServlet", value = "/hello-servlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String message;

    public void init() {
        message = "Hello World!";
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        // Hello
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
        for (String book : DBHandler.getBooks()) {
            out.print(book + "</br>");
        }
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

DBHandler

```
package com.ex.dynamicweb;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DBHandler {

    private static final String SELECT_ALL_FROM_LIBRARY = "SELECT * FROM library.books";

    public static List<String> getBooks() {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres";
        String user = "postgres";
        String password = "1234";

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,
                user, password)) {
            System.out.println("Java JDBC PostgreSQL Example");

            System.out.println("Connected to PostgreSQL database!");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SELECT_ALL_FROM_LIBRARY);
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                result.add(resultSet.getString("NAME") + "- id: " + resultSet.getString("ID"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection failure.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

[Artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdUuB.png)

[Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOaqh.png)

[Modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOk5b.png)

Comment: A clarification I forgot to mention: the error occurs when directly navigating to the HelloServlet page. The page itself is displayed, but there is no list of books; instead, an error is encountered.

Comment: what build system do you use and how are you adding that library to it?

Comment: @bilak I'm using maven. I tried to add it in all possible ways - into pom.xml with further rebooting and rebuilding of everything possible (both server and project), and manually through Libraries, Artifacts, Modules tabs in Project Settings. Nothing helps - stacktrace does not change. The last option - manual addition - is attached in screenshots

Comment: The `Class.forName()` line has been redundant since 2006. It did not form part of the solution to this problem. All it does now is change the symptom.

Comment: @user207421 This option worked for me. The problem is that when I import the driver through maven, it appears in the Project Structure section in both Libraries and Modules -> Dependencies. But the error I wrote in the question keeps appearing without adding the Class.forName() construct.

Comment: The fact you did need `Class.forName` is that you're using Tomcat, and automatic driverloading will have already run at the the time your WAR is loaded. That means drivers in the WAR are not subject to automatic driverloading, and you need to load it explicitly. That said, you shouldn't use `DriverManager` in a web application, you should use a `javax.sql.DataSource` implementation backed by a connection pool (Tomcat comes with one built-in, but there are also others).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using maven and you've probably just added library in intellij?

Try to add following to your `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: (1/2) As I mentioned in the question, I have already tried this option. I added the driver to pom.xml, and also checked the build results (in the target folder), artefacts, "modules" and "libraries" sections - everywhere the driver was added, but the problem still persisted and the stacktrace did not change.
In advance of the question - yes, I updated the project and reloaded the IDE. Nothing has changed. I did a rebuild of the project, including complete deletion of the traget folder, and nothing changed.

Comment: (2/2) At the same time, connection directly to the database for writing queries through the IDE is successful, the driver works fine there. Is there any way to add the driver to the server classpath, as it is done in Eclipse?

Comment: Just tried removing the driver from everywhere, importing it again via maven and prescribing Class.forName(). It worked this time. Apparently, I have tried every option except the only right one